# Why does \narrower not work in LaTeX as in plain TeX?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

In the TeXbook (page 100), `\narrower` is described and the following example provided, which works fine in plain TeX.

> ```tex
> {\narrower\smallskip\noindent
> This paragraph will have narrower lines than
> the surrounding paragraphs do, because it
> uses the ``narrower'' feature of plain \TeX.
> The former margins will be restored after
> this group ends.\smallskip}
> ```

However, this does not work in LaTeX. An additional `\par` at the end of the `\narrower` paragraph remedies the situation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}\makeatletter

This is a normal paragraph.

{\narrower\smallskip\noindent
  This should be a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using plain \TeX's ``narrower'' feature as described in the \TeX book.
  However, it does not really appear to be narrower.
  \smallskip
}

{\narrower\smallskip\noindent
  This is a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using plain \TeX's ``narrower'' feature with a trailing \verb|\par|.
  Nowadays, you should use a \LaTeX\ environment, though.
  \par\smallskip
}

This is a normal paragraph again.
Let's make it a bit longer, in order to see its right margin.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Why is that? Shouldn't the `\smallskip` end the paragraph, even without the `\par` (as it does in plain TeX)?

Comment: @campa Ah, should have read more carefully. You are absolutely right. Feel free to post an answer. Do you know why this change was made? After all, the name `\smallskip` indicates a skip..

Comment: @schtandard `\vspace` is LaTeX's standard interface for vertical spacing, so this ensures that they behave the same as normal LaTeX commands for vertical skips. Especially this allows `\smallskip` to be used to adjust spacing in paragraphs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is in the definition of `\smallskip` (and the same for `\medskip` and `\bigskip`). Plain TeX defines

```
\def\smallskip{\vskip\smallskipamount}
```

while LaTeX does

```
\def\smallskip{\vspace\smallskipamount}
```

Now, `\vskip` is a TeX primitive which ends the current paragraph when issued in (unrestricted) horizontal mode. On the other end, `\vspace` is a LaTeX macro which expands on `\vskip` *when in vertical mode*, and in `\vadjust` otherwise. The paragraph in your first example is therefore not ended before the group is closed.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that `\narrower` is defined in LaTeX is incidental and should not be relied upon. It stems from the fact that the original LaTeX format was based on a slightly modified version of `plain.tex` in order to ease transition from plain TeX documents to LaTeX ones.

campa has already explained the reason why `\smallskip` works differently in LaTeX than in plain TeX. But the *real* solution is to define your own environment using LaTeX features such as `\addvspace`, so two consecutive environments will not add twice the space and you don't need to manually add or remove `\smallskip` in case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{latexnarrower}
  {\par\addvspace{\smallskipamount}\narrower\noindent\ignorespaces}
  {\par\addvspace{\smallskipamount}}

\begin{document}

This is a normal paragraph.

{\smallskip\narrower\noindent
  This should be a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using plain \TeX's ``narrower'' feature as described in the \TeX book.
  but corrected for \LaTeX{} usage. And you see that it is indeed narrower, because
  we added \verb|\par| at the end.\par\smallskip
}

{\smallskip\narrower\noindent
  This should be a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using plain \TeX's ``narrower'' feature as described in the \TeX book.
  but corrected for \LaTeX{} usage. And you see that it is indeed narrower, because
  we added \verb|\par| at the end.\par\smallskip
}

This is a normal paragraph, long enough to wrap across lines. Let's just make it
long enough. Perhaps this does the job.

\begin{latexnarrower}
  This is a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using a proper \LaTeX{} environment. Which is surely a better
  way to do the job.
\end{latexnarrower}

\begin{latexnarrower}
  This is a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using a proper \LaTeX{} environment. Which is surely a better
  way to do the job.
\end{latexnarrower}

This is a normal paragraph, long enough to wrap across lines. Let's just make it
long enough. Perhaps this does the job.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you spot the difference?

Even better you can use a `list` so you can use other LaTeX features.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{latexnarrower}
 {\list{}{\topsep=\smallskipamount\leftmargin=\parindent\rightmargin=\parindent}\item}
 {\endlist}

\begin{document}

This is a normal paragraph.

{\smallskip\narrower\noindent
  This should be a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using plain \TeX's ``narrower'' feature as described in the \TeX book.
  but corrected for \LaTeX{} usage. And you see that it is indeed narrower, because
  we added \verb|\par| at the end.\par\smallskip
}

{\smallskip\narrower\noindent
  This should be a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using plain \TeX's ``narrower'' feature as described in the \TeX book.
  but corrected for \LaTeX{} usage. And you see that it is indeed narrower, because
  we added \verb|\par| at the end.\par\smallskip
}

This is a normal paragraph, long enough to wrap across lines. Let's just make it
long enough. Perhaps this does the job.

\begin{latexnarrower}
  This is a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using a proper \LaTeX{} environment. Which is surely a better
  way to do the job.
\end{latexnarrower}

\begin{latexnarrower}
  This is a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using a proper \LaTeX{} environment. Which is surely a better
  way to do the job.
\end{latexnarrower}

This is a normal paragraph, long enough to wrap across lines. Let's just make it
long enough. Perhaps this does the job.

\begin{latexnarrower}
  This is a narrower paragraph.
  It was created using a proper \LaTeX{} environment. Which is surely a better
  way to do the job.
\end{latexnarrower}
This is a normal paragraph, long enough to wrap across lines. Let's just make it
long enough. You see it has no indentation, because there was no blank line
between \verb|\end{latexnarrower}| and the following text.

\end{document}
```

[image]